# Where all should i Register and Unregister Boadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My code is working but where is the appropriate places to register and unregister broadcast receivers ? Should broadcasts be registered on the onCreate method or right before they receive data ? ???
Thanks for the advice in advanced.

Comment: It depends on which broadcasts you're trying to receive, and when you want to receive them.

Comment: is it bad practice to leave broadcast receivers running for the length of the activity? Most of my receivers are related to services (sending and retrieving data).

Comment: They won't really run unless a broadcast they're registered for is sent, but no, it's not necessarily bad practice to have one registered for the entire time that an `Activity` is active. In that case, you'd want to register in `onResume()`, and unregister in `onPause()`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!